# Объединение ячеек таблицы

Tags: html5

Всем привет. Есть таблица. Необходимо объединить нижние ячейки с картинками в ряд с другими двумя. Пробую rowspan, но не помогает.

[image: таблица]

Как можно их объединить? Прилагаю код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <table style="font-family:Arial;font-size:80%; ">

    <td style="padding:0" rowspan="6">
      <a href="http://www.independentaviation.com.au/" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://www.independentaviation.com.au/sig_new/2/independent.jpg" style="width: 180px;">
      </a>
    </td>

    <tr>
      <td style="padding:0">
        <b style="font-size: 15px;">Phoebe Munchow</b>Sales &amp; Marketing Executive
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td style="padding:0">
        INDEPENDENT AVIATION PTY LTD
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td style="padding:0">
        AUSTRALIAN & INTERNATIONAL AIR CHARTER BROKERS
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td style="padding:0">
        INT. PH: +617 4046 3333| 24HRS PH: 1300 247 242| m: 0457 293 232
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td style="padding:0">
        phoebe@independentaviation.com.au |www.independentaviation.com.au
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="nbaa.png" style="width: 190px;">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="facebook.png" style="width: 150px;">
      </td>
    </tr>


  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень понял какие именно картинки нужно положить в один ряд, но ряд это теги . Сейчас у тебя в 1 ряду 1 картинка.

```
 <tr>
  <td>
    <img src="nbaa.png" style="width: 190px;">
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
    <img src="facebook.png" style="width: 150px;">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Соответственно, чтобы было в одном ряду 2 или более картинок - нужно сделать так

```
 <tr>
  <td>
    <img src="nbaa.png" style="width: 190px;">
  </td>
  <td>
    <img src="facebook.png" style="width: 150px;">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Далее - по аналогии.
Ну если так - то:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
<table style="font-family:Arial;font-size:80%; ">
<tr>
    <td style="padding:0" rowspan="6">
        <a href="http://www.independentaviation.com.au/" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://www.independentaviation.com.au/sig_new/2/independent.jpg" style="width: 180px;">
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td style="padding:0">
        <b style="font-size: 15px;">Phoebe Munchow</b>Sales &amp; Marketing Executive
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="nbaa.png" style="width: 190px;">
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="facebook.png" style="width: 150px;">
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td style="padding:0">
        INDEPENDENT AVIATION PTY LTD
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td style="padding:0">
        AUSTRALIAN & INTERNATIONAL AIR CHARTER BROKERS
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td style="padding:0">
        INT. PH: +617 4046 3333| 24HRS PH: 1300 247 242| m: 0457 293 232
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td style="padding:0">
        phoebe@independentaviation.com.au |www.independentaviation.com.au
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: извините не до конца объяснил. Исправил картинку.

Comment: поправил ответ, с учетом дополнений

Comment: простите мою наглость но как можно было бы подставить правую картинку под левую?Я просто уже окончательно запутался с рядами и rowspanam-и. Я картинку тоже приложил. Спасибо вам заранее.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/47yt62fc/ единственное, посмотрите по стилю. может вам поправить отступы и т.п. надо